# Retrieve more than 200 rows in data model in BI publisher

Tags: oracle, datamodel, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

I was trying to retrieve  more than 200 rows from the table, but BI publisher data model gives only maximum of 200 rows only. How to retrieve more than 200 rows.

[image]

Comment: Check this out : http://drmcnatty.com/retrieve-all-data-rows-for-report-design/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to Oracle Document 1679689.1,Starting with Oracle BI Publisher version 11.1.8.0.0 and later, when in the Data Model design window, the “Data” preview tab is now limited to 200 rows

But you can do this by following the below steps :

1. When building the data model, on the Data Sets, Data tab, you
   have the option to view and export (to XML) your sample data.
2. Create the Data Mode
3. Create a simple layout design and then link
   that layout design to your data model.
4. Click the View a List in
   the layout design, select the Output Formats and make sure that Data
   (XML) option is checked and then SAVE the layout.
5. Click “View Report”.
6. Vlick the action dropdown and select Export, XML Data as
   the option.
7. Save this XML output on your local machine.
8. Use this XML to inspect the entire data set for completeness and integrity.
9. Once loaded, the BI Preview options (PDF, etc.) will output the
   report with the complete data as you would expect.

For more reference you check this document [here](http://drmcnatty.com/retrieve-all-data-rows-for-report-design/)

Comment: I earlier followed the same link that you shared, but view and export will only export what row number you selected from the drop down